# Oops! Something Bad Happened! When Applying for a Job?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've been trying to apply for a job on stackoverflow.com/jobs for the last three days, and I keep getting the same error message every time I try.

**Oops! Something Bad Happened!**

I think three days are more than enough to fix a production issue like this !

Any ideas what's going on ? or when is this going to be fixed ?

Thanks

Comment: Ummmm, well it is the *weekend*. Looking at it now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just pushed a fix to production. We made a change on Friday that assumed that a geo-located location from the Google Places API always had a country code. Turns out that isn't a safe assumption; your location in the Google Places API doesn't. I've added some defensive code around that block and things should be back to normal.

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Maybe best not to [deploy on a Friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115612/why-not-to-deploy-on-a-friday)

Comment: @MartinSmith we deploy to production many times a day, every day. Heck I just deployed twice on a Sunday. We feature flag large new features but sadly this bug was the result of another bug fix. Fortunately it only affected a few people.

Comment: People also tend to forget that _shit happens_. Expecting 100% uptime and perfection is just as irresponsible on the consumer end as it is the developer end.